# I'm trying to hide/show divs on menu click

Tags: javascript, html, menu, swap

I have a div for my menu `<div class="menu">` coded as such; `<a href="#" onclick="show('about')">About Us</a>`
I have a div for my pages `<div class="pages">` which contains many pages under different div ids. Example; `<div id="about" style='display:block'>`
Javascipt:

```
<script>
        function show(target){
        document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
        }
        function hide(target){
        document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
        }


    </script>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but what the divs are SUPPOSE to do is swap out based on menu click.

Comment: You have to hide all the other divs too, not just show the one where the link is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle('about');">About Us</a>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle('contact');">Contact</a>

<div class="article" id="about" style="display:none;">ABOUT ARTICLE...</div>
<div class="article" id="contact" style="display:none;">CONTACT ARTICLE...</div>
```

```
function toggle(target){

  var artz = document.getElementsByClassName('article');
  var targ = document.getElementById(target);  
  var isVis = targ.style.display=='block';

  // hide all
  for(var i=0;i<artz.length;i++){
     artz[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  // toggle current
  targ.style.display = isVis?'none':'block';

  return false;
}
```

**➨**   *[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fSHD7/2/)*

Comment: This works the best! One issue though. The pages don't override each other. Any tips? What I mean is that the 'about' page needs to somehow hide when I click on a different menu option. If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first have all the divs hidden except the one initially showed, then return false to prevent your link's default action incase it had an anchor

```
    function show(target){
       document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
       return false;
    }
    function hide(target){
       document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
       return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide all the pages first, and then show the one that is selected. You also need to handle the default behavior of the link (which is page navigation)

This will likely work with your existing HTML:

```
function show(target){
    hideAllPages();//hide all pages
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';//show selected page
    return false;//cancel page navigation
}

function hideAllPages(){
    var pages = document.getElementsByClassName("pages");
    for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++){
        pages[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```